# Mongo `await FindAsync` doesn't compile.

Tags: c#, mongodb, visual-studio-2010, async-await

When I try to use the `await` keyword with the `FindAll(filter)` method I end up with un-compilable code.  e.g.:

```
using (var cursor = await collection.FindAsync(filter))
{
    while (await cursor.MoveNextAsync())
    {
        var batch = cursor.Current;
        foreach (var document in batch)
        {
            // process document
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

is giving:

```
The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'.
```

If I look at the source, the method is indeed returning a `Task`:

```
public static Task<IAsyncCursor<TDocument>> FindAsync<TDocument>(...)
```

Any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your** function is not marked as async, not the mongo one but yours, the one which has the code.

In order to make async calls inside a function you must mark that function as async:

```
public async void YourFunction()
{ 
    //Here you can use await
}
```

Else you will receive that compile error.

Comment: That's it, thanks you.  It was a in a test method and it didn't occur to me!

Comment: `async void`? Definitely a no no. Make it `async Task`.

Answer (score 0):

Your function should be async.
i.e.

`async Task<int> myFunc()`
Instead of
`int myFunc ()`